# No value accessor for form control with name error in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm using angular 7. And I have parent and child component like below Stackblitz. But, I'm giving `formControlName` from child component. When, I wrote "id" instead of  `formControlName`, everything working perfectly. But, when I wrote `formControlName`, then it gave me error **No value accessor for form control with name: 'brand'**

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-3zykuz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**I added this code which I saw from other post, to app.module.ts for solving, but it didn't work.**

```
providers: [
  { 
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    multi: true,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyChildComponentComponent),
  }
]
```

Comment: This is not duplicate. I applied solution accepted in that question. But, it didn't work for me. My problem is different. @PrashantPimpale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your app component like:

```
<app-my-child-component formControlName="brand"></app-my-child-component>
```

Add the provider in the component not on the module and implement "ControlValueAccessor" methods there.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-child-component',
  templateUrl: './my-child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-child-component.component.css'],
  providers:
    [ { 
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    multi: true,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyChildComponentComponent),
  }],
})
export class MyChildComponentComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  value: string;
  onChange() {}
  onTouched() {}
  isDisabled: boolean = false;

  writeValue(value) {
    this.value = value
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled) {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

}
```

No need of another form in `child component`, it will be something like:

```
<input 
  [value]="value"
  (input)="onChange($event.target.value)"
  (blur)="onTouched()"
  [disabled]="isDisabled"
  type="text">
```

See a stack blitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-ccj26w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-child-component%2Fmy-child-component.component.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot @xyz.  It worked. My mistake is adding to `app.module.ts`. But, right place was `child-component.ts`

Comment: But, if I write like your said, `<input [value]="value" type="text">`, then it will give me error when I add second input. Am I right @xyz?

Comment: @realist what  is second input? See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-hedcny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-child-component%2Fmy-child-component.component.html

Comment: @realist Implement all the method of control value accessor, register functions, setDisabledState etc. This way you will be able to achieve all the functionalities of the reactive form

Comment: I looked your stackblitz. And I learnt now that, I'm always used wrong way 
up to the now. Thanks a lot. You lighten me.

Comment: When I changed "haha" text to "asdfg" in your stackblitz, and then click "SAVE". It gave me again "haha" in my console. What can be the reason of this @xyz

Comment: @realist: as said previously, you have to register the functions, check my edit now, open the stackblitz in the answer.

Comment: Ok. I now understood completely. Thanks a lot again.